# Parsing String date to date

Tags: java, parsing, date, date-formatting

I have a date String in this format "YYYY-MM-dd HH::mm:ss". Every time i parse the string i get wrong date.("Sun Dec 29 10:10:10 CET 2013"). The code is below:

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date startDate = timeFormat.parse("2014-08-10 10:10:10");
System.out.println(startDate);
```

This returns "Sun Dec 29 10:10:10 CET 2013". How to correctly parse the date String?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `YYYY` you will need to use `yyyy`.

`Y` Refers to WEEK_YEAR whereas `y` refers to YEAR. WEEK_YEARs are based on when the first full week of a year starts (this differs depending on settings), and thus are slightly (and sometimes largely) different from that of YEAR.

See the javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong format. You need `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

If you take a look at [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you will find that

```
y   Year
Y   Week year
```

where "[week year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year)" is in sync with a [WEEK_OF_YEAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR) cycle.

Now, why `YYYY` returns 2013 for year `2014`?

To answer this question you need to understand how calendar determines that week belongs to some year. Rule is quite simple:

- week belongs to year XXXX if last `N` days of this week (usually N=4 but it is determined by `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek` from used Calendar) belongs to year XXXX
- weeks starts at day which is result from `getFirstDayOfWeek`. This result depends on Locale but in next examples we will use Monday as first day of week.

**Example 1.**

Assuming that first day of week is Monday and days required for week to belong to some year is 4 lets try to determine which week is first in year XXXX for January which looks like this:

```
       January XXXX
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun 
 27  28  29  30  31   1   2
  3   4   5   6   7   8   9
...
```

Week from first row contains only two days which belongs to year XXXX (to January), 1st and 2nd

```
 27  28  29  30  31   1   2
                    ^^^ ^^^  //days which belong to January
```

but this is less than number of days required for this week to belong to XXXX year while next week

```
  3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

contains 7 days which belong to XXXX year. Since week in first row doesn't belong to year XXXX *first week* in *week year* will start 3 January XXXX. This means that if we parse value `XXXX` with format `YYYY` we will get `3rd January XXXX`.

**Example 2.**

Now lets say that calendar for year XXXX looks like this

```
       January XXXX
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun 
 30  31   1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12
...
```

As you can see in week

```
 30  31   1   2   3   4   5
```

its last 5 days belong to year XXXX which is more than required 4 days
 -> which means that this week belongs to year XXXX,
 -> and it is also first week of XXXX year
 -> which means that first week of this year starts at `30 December (XXXX-1)`
 -> which finally means that if you parse such year using `YYYY` format you will get value XXXX-1.

---

**Example 2** is actually situation from year `2014`, which is why year was interpreted as year `2013`.

BTW, if you would decide to use format with week year to set month and day you would also need to use special formats which would describe

- which week of year you want to set
- and which day of week

so instead of `M` and `d` you would have to use

```
w   Week in year
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)
```

(hours, minutes, seconds are part of time rather than date so `H` `m` and `s` are fine in this format)

for instance

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-ww-uu HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2004-53-7 10:10:10");
System.out.println(date);
```

which will be parsed to `Sun Jan 02 10:10:10 CET 2005`

Comment: More comment than answer?

Comment: @hd1 it is solution (so answer, low quality but still answer), I am working on "why" part.

Comment: If it solves the problem, accept the answer and ignore my comment

Comment: The "why" is that `YYYY` is the [week-year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), which is different from the year, [represented as `yyyy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @hd1 Is it still more comment than answer?