# Transform a String in unix time java android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, epoch

At the moment I have a String with the folowing format :

'DD/MM/YYYY' , and I'm willing to store this in a SQLite database as a date.

Since it is impossible to store it as a datetime, I've decided Integers would be the best choice, and someone told me about the Unix epoch solution. The thing is that I'm very unfamiliar with that, and I can't seem to convert a String into a unix epoch time...

Is there a way to directly convert a String with my format into a unix epoch time, or am I doing it wrong and should I change something?

I've read this question :[Unix epoch time to Java Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object) But still can not find my way out with my String...

Comment: There are *lots* of questions about parsing a string representation of a date. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+parse+string+date

Comment: Learn about ISO 8601 formats.

Comment: Also duplicates [Best way to work with dates in Android SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363112/642706), and many many others.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Parsing String date to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748118/parsing-string-date-to-date) and adjust the format to yours.

If you have a `java.util.Date` just use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() to get the UNIX timestamp as `long`.

Comment: Oh I just have to do a double conversion then, why didn't I think of that before... Sorry for the inconvenience, thanks for the doc, I'll use it!

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, read the docs! ;)

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.parse(<value>);
```